# Creating a counter saved in Parse in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, counter

I am trying to create a counter of points that every user is earning while using my app. I want to save the counter in back-end parse.

Here is the code I am using,

Creating the counter,

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
gameScore.setObject(0, forKey: "score")
gameScore.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "username")
gameScore.saveInBackground()
```

Updating the counter by 5,

```
 var oldScore = Int?()
 var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
 var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
 query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (gameResult: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
 if error == nil {
 let firstObject = gameResult![0]
 oldScore = firstObject["score"] as? Int
 }

 gameScore.setObject(oldScore! + 5, forKey: "score")
 gameScore.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "username")
```

This does not seem to be the best method, as I am not using the inbuilt functions of Parse object like incrementKey()
Also every time I am updating I end up creating a new row for the same user. Also the value of counter does not increase but stays zero. Is there a better way to do this at a user level?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop creating new objects for the score, test if a score object exists for that user before creating it. You already have the code for that in:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (gameResult: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 

    ...
```

Just add a check like

```
if gameResult.count == 0 {
    // Create a new game score here.
    var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
    gameScore.setObject(0, forKey: "score")
    gameScore.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "username")
    gameScore.saveInBackground()
}
```

When increasing the score, use increment key to save the need for extra code:

```
gameScore.incrementKey("score", byAmount: 5)
gameScore.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: Daniel, when running gameScore.incrementKey("score", byAmount: 5), how will Xcode know what user score are we updating?

Comment: If you have code to create the object per user and then increment per user, it will be helpful

Comment: The user is known when you `gameScore.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "username")`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working this way, thanks Daniel

```
//Creating an object if not present already
let query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
                query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (gameResult: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if gameResult!.count == 0 {
                        let gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore")
                        gameScore.setObject(5, forKey: "score")
                        gameScore.setObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, forKey: "username")
                        gameScore.saveInBackground()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let obj = gameResult![0]
                        obj.incrementKey("score", byAmount: 5)
                        obj.saveInBackground()
                    }
```